# Topological applications of topological entropy

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, entropy

I just learned [topological entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_entropy) during a lecture about dynamical systems, and I wonder whether there exist purely topological applications of it.

Comment: purely topological as opposed to applications in topologic dynamics?

Comment: By *purely topological applications*, I thought about problems which can be formulated without using the vocabulary of dynamcal systems.

Comment: How do you expect to have a topological entropy without a map ? Once you have a map, you are in domain of dynamical systems.

Comment: A map could appear in the proof and not in the result. Moreover, I did not say that the problem has to be completely disjoint from dynamical systems, but that it should be possible to formulate it without any specific knowledge about them.